# Java tool for Lemmatization

Tags: java, lemmatization

I need to perform lemmatization on English, including adjectives:

e.g. Mexican --> Mexico

Can you recommend any tools, preferably in Java.

I want to stress that I am looking for lemmatization, not stemming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Lemmatization java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java)