# Filter words belonging to a broad category

Tags: java, nlp

I have a list of words (assume they are stored in String[] if you must). I want to filter out words that belong to a broad general category such as *Music* or *Sports*.

Is there a ready-made solution for this (even if it's only for a limited set of general categories)?

Or how would you go about doing this?

It is to be done in *Java 1.6* and it is an NLP (Natural Language Processing) problem. The input list of words has random words, and I want to extract from this large list, only the words that belong to a given general category (which will be a subset).

**Another way of thinking:** Given a single word, I want to determine if this word belongs to a category. *Something like this:*

```
String word1 = "football"; //the strings will always be single word units
String word2 = "telephone";
boolean b1 = belongsToCategory(Categories.SPORTS, word1); //true
boolean b2 = belongsToCategory(Categories.SPORTS, word2); //false
```

If you need more info, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my idea would be to hold a set of words for each category and look the word up in each set.

Of course, this set would get huge and impossible to maintain if you held all the inflected forms for a single word. I'd consider using lemmatization to limit the size of this set.
You might be interested in checking the following links:
[Lemmatization on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatization)
and
[Lemmatization java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java)

Comment: I'm doing something like that right now, since there are no ready-made solution suggestions that offer advantages. But I will look into Lemmatization later (I found that using a Stemmer sucks).