# Lemmatization NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, lemmatization

i have an Exception in lemmatization code in java by using Netbeans 8.0 (that exists in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java)) when put it in my project which consists of many classes. the Exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.stanford.nlp.process.Morphology.lemma(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.MorphaAnnotator.addLemma(MorphaAnnotator.java:72)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.MorphaAnnotator.annotate(MorphaAnnotator.java:56)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotationPipeline.annotate(AnnotationPipeline.java:69)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.annotate(StanfordCoreNLP.java:684)
    at summerization.StanfordLemmatizer.lemmatize(StanfordLemmatizer.java:64)
    at summerization.StanfordLemmatizer.main(StanfordLemmatizer.java:100)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the code that leads to this stack trace.

Comment: this.pipeline.annotate(document); System.out.println(slem.lemmatize(text)); the Exception appeared in the previous lines. Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 1):

Usually `NoSuchMethodError` implies you're using a different version in compile time and runtime. Make sure that you have the same jar (version) in the classpath that this method comes from.

You didn't provide enough information but if you use maven you can run `dependency:tree` to see your dependencies. Make sure the jar does not repeat itself twice and that the version is correct. Afterwards, make sure that in the runtime environment you use the same jar as in dev.

Comment: Thanks alot .....the code run without Exception