# Lemmatizer class java

Tags: java, class, lemmatization

I am looking for a "simple" way to lemmatize a String or file.txt 
Does someone know an opensource class which lemmatize ?

All i can find on google is librairies and packages, I have no clue how does it work and how to use them in a java project.

Comment: Please read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), in particular, bullet pt 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this:

[Lemmatization java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java)

There is a lemmatization program called Stanford CoreNLP [(download here)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) that may be useful to you. I believe it is open source.

I hope this helps,

Santiago