# Ignore words for lemmatizer

Tags: stanford-nlp

I would like to use Stanford CoreNLP for lemmatization but I have some words not to be lemmatized. Is there a way to provide this ignore list to the tool? I am following this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java), and when the program calls `this.pipeline.annotate(document);`then, that's it; it would be hard to replace the occurrences. One solution is that create a mapping list in which each word to be ignored is paired with lemmatize(word) (i.e., d = {(w1, lemmatize(w1)), (w2, lemmatize(w2), ...} and do the post processing with this mapping list. But it should be easier than this, I guess.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution with my friend's help.

```
  for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {
        // Iterate over all tokens in a sentence
        for (CoreLabel token: sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
            System.out.print(token.get(OriginalTextAnnotation.class) + "\t");
            System.out.println(token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class));

        }
    }
```

You can get original form of the word by calling `token.get(OriginalTextAnnotation.class)`.