# Java library to parse text and count number of unique words?

Tags: java, parsing, dictionary

I would like to count how many unique words are used in some text. Tricky part is, that I would like to consider **different forms of one word as just one word**. Example:

```
I work.
He works.
I am working.
I have worked.
```

Unique words in this text are just these 5: [I, work, He, am, have] because there are 4 different forms of one (same) word - work.

I quess I need some dictionary for this, or some library, but after some googling didn't find anything. Anybody can help me? Thanks!

PS: I know that some words are exactly same, but their meaning is different. (example: When he **leaves** home, the **leaves** will cover the ground). Anyway, just ignore such cases - it's hard to cover them + they are rare and can't significantly affect the result.

Comment: @ryekayo How is regex going to help him with "go", "goes", "went", "gone"? And OP, how are you going to deal with "When he **leaves** home, the **leaves** will cover the ground"? Duplicate or unique?

Comment: @RealSkeptic as such cases are not possible to distiguish, I can consider them as same words - this is acceptable "bug". It happens just rarely, and it won't affect the result too much. All I want is to deal with most common cases of duplicating words.

Comment: I would recommend using an english [word stemmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) and finding the unique root stems of your corpus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For english language, you could use `PorterStemmer` from lucene's distribution. The idea is to keep for each word its stem, and store it to a set.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PorterStemmer;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> stems = new HashSet<>();

        PorterStemmer stemmer = new PorterStemmer();
        String strings[] = new String[] { "I work.", "He works.",
                "I am working.", "I have worked." };
        for (String s : strings) {
            for (String word : s.split("[\\s\\.]+")) {
                stemmer.setCurrent(word);
                stemmer.stem();
                stems.add(stemmer.getCurrent());
            }
        }
        System.err.println(stems);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[work, have, am, I, He]
```

If you decide to use lucene, you can start also using lucene's more advanced tokenizer functions. In the above example, we just split on whitespace and dot characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [*stemming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) library. I haven't used one directly (only through indexing process of [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org). There is an [API](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/package-summary.html) that can filter the words of your text to remove all related words as part of a preprocessing before counting the frequencies.

But there exists many implementation, for instance [this one](http://trimc-nlp.blogspot.fr/2013/08/snowball-stemmer-for-java.html).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page hosted by the Stanford NLP Group](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html), you could use *stemming* or *lemmatization* to achieve what you want:

> *Stemming* usually refers to a crude heuristic process that chops off the ends of words in the hope of achieving this goal correctly most of the time, and often includes the removal of derivational affixes. *Lemmatization* usually refers to doing things properly with the use of a vocabulary and morphological analysis of words, normally aiming to remove inflectional endings only and to return the base or dictionary form of a word, which is known as the *lemma*.

From all the links provided in that page, the only one that works is [PorterStemmer](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/), whose usage is explained in another answer.

For a lemmatizer, see [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java), which suggests you use the [Stanford Core NLP library](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP).