# Tagging word and sentence using stanford corenlp library fails

Tags: stanford-nlp

```
 //tagger
      MaxentTagger tagger = new MaxentTagger(args[0]);
      TokenizerFactory<CoreLabel> ptbTokenizerFactory = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(),
                                   "untokenizable=noneKeep");
      BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(args[1]), "utf-8"));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "utf-8"));
      DocumentPreprocessor documentPreprocessor = new DocumentPreprocessor(r);
      documentPreprocessor.setTokenizerFactory(ptbTokenizerFactory);
      for (List<HasWord> sentence : documentPreprocessor) {
        List<TaggedWord> tSentence = tagger.tagSentence(sentence);
        pw.println(Sentence.listToString(tSentence, false));
      }
```

It fails with following exception
Reading POS tagger model from C:\work\development\workspace\stanfordnlp\sample.txt ...

```
C:\work\development\workspace\stanfordnlp\sample.txtException in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:869)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:767)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:298)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.<init>(MaxentTagger.java:263)
    at phoenix.TokenizerDemo.main(TokenizerDemo.java:42)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 416E6F74
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TaggerConfig.readConfig(TaggerConfig.java:748)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.readModelAndInit(MaxentTagger.java:804)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The log should clearly indicate the problem:

> Reading POS tagger model from C:\work\development\workspace\stanfordnlp\sample.txt ...

You are incorrectly instantiating the `MaxentTagger` instance. If you provide a single string argument to the constructor, that string is expected to provide a path to a tagger model file.

See the [documentation for `MaxentTagger`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/MaxentTagger.html#MaxentTagger-java.lang.String-) for more information.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My project is a java maven project and I added coreNLP and models in my POM file, no path to model files or anything.. my code is the exact code as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java).