# Stanford NLP -- specifying a POS

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I downloaded and successfully added the Stanford NLP libraries to my project. Following this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578062/lemmatization-java), it worked perfectly. However, is there a way to specify the 'POS' to be searched? Or is it possible?

Example: If you used the word `creation`, is it possible to set the POS Tag to verb so that it will return `create` rather than `creation`?

Answer (score 1):

POS tagging will not suggest words for you. It will provide the results as per your trained model. You need to write your own layer above pos tagger which will do this stuff. A suggestion would be to user completionsuggest of elasticsearch.